# Pl/SQL problem with syntax in validation code

Tags: sql, plsql

Trying to write this type of script in PL / SQL on the second line with "WHEN", I get a syntax error. Please help
The function should validate and contain the logic it is trying to write

I don't have much experience. How could I write it differently?

```
create or replace FUNCTION BUSINESS_PROVIDER_GET(valueGet IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS
      v_value business_provider_configuration.billing_account_id%TYPE ;
    BEGIN
    DECLARE
            V_BUSINESS_PROVIDER  business_provider_configuration.business_provider%TYPE; 
            V_TRADING_NAME   business_provider_configuration.trading_name%TYPE; 
            V_CUSTOMER_ID business_provider_configuration.customer_id%TYPE;
            V_PROVIDER BUSINESS_PROVIDER_CONFIGURATION%TYPE;

    BEGIN
            SELECT
            *
            INTO V_BUSINESS_PROVIDER
            FROM
            BUSINESS_PROVIDER_CONFIGURATION
            WHERE 
            V_BUSINESS_PROVIDER = valueGet
            AND
            Upper(V_BUSINESS_PROVIDER) = Upper (valueGet);
            EXCEPTION
            WHEN no_data_found THEN

            SELECT
            *
            INTO V_TRADING_NAME
            FROM
            BUSINESS_PROVIDER_CONFIGURATION
            WHERE 
            V_TRADING_NAME = valueGet
            AND
            Upper(V_TRADING_NAME) = Upper (valueGet);
            EXCEPTION
            WHEN no_data_found THEN

            SELECT
            *
            INTO V_CUSTOMER_ID
            FROM
            BUSINESS_PROVIDER_CONFIGURATION
            WHERE 
            V_CUSTOMER_ID = valueGet
            AND
            Upper(V_CUSTOMER_ID) = Upper (valueGet);

            EXCEPTION
            WHEN no_data_found
            raise_application_error(-20000, 'Not found');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exception is 'end-of-block' keyword - you can't just pull it out of nowhere multiple times in the same block.

In function you are allowed to have one exception statement, because function body is block on it's own.

If inside exception block you want to handle another exception, the code which may raise that exception must be inside a block.

It helps a lot to fix such issues when code is properly indented - i had to do it here:

```
create or replace FUNCTION BUSINESS_PROVIDER_GET(valueGet IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS
        v_value business_provider_configuration.billing_account_id%TYPE ;
    BEGIN
    DECLARE
        V_BUSINESS_PROVIDER  business_provider_configuration.business_provider%TYPE; 
        V_TRADING_NAME   business_provider_configuration.trading_name%TYPE; 
        V_CUSTOMER_ID business_provider_configuration.customer_id%TYPE;
        V_PROVIDER BUSINESS_PROVIDER_CONFIGURATION%TYPE;
    BEGIN
        SELECT *
          INTO V_BUSINESS_PROVIDER
          FROM BUSINESS_PROVIDER_CONFIGURATION
         WHERE V_BUSINESS_PROVIDER = valueGet
           AND Upper(V_BUSINESS_PROVIDER) = Upper (valueGet);
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN no_data_found THEN
            BEGIN -- Block that can raise second exception
                SELECT *
                  INTO V_TRADING_NAME
                  FROM BUSINESS_PROVIDER_CONFIGURATION
                 WHERE V_TRADING_NAME = valueGet
                   AND Upper(V_TRADING_NAME) = Upper (valueGet);
            EXCEPTION
            WHEN no_data_found THEN
                BEGIN -- Block that can raise third exception
                    SELECT *
                      INTO V_CUSTOMER_ID
                      FROM BUSINESS_PROVIDER_CONFIGURATION
                     WHERE V_CUSTOMER_ID = valueGet
                       AND Upper(V_CUSTOMER_ID) = Upper (valueGet);
                EXCEPTION
                    WHEN no_data_found
                        raise_application_error(-20000, 'Not found');
                END; -- End of block that can raise third exception
            END; -- End of block that can raise second exception
    END BUSINESS_PROVIDER_GET; -- End of function body
```

I do not have your tables so i was not able to test it, there might still be some issues here.

Also, the code is a little bit of mess- you should not have to look in multiple columns that have distinct business meaning for just one value.

And i have no idea, how do you want to 'select *' into single scalar variable from a table, that has multiple columns - just specify, which column you want to fetch.
I would argue that 'select *' should never be used in stored code, unless you fetch into record variable that inherits rowtype from table.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the conditions as you are using them will never return any values. You are defining the variable, for example V_BUSINESS_PROVIDER and right after that compare it against valueGet. Since the V_BUSINESS_PROVIDER is null the result of conditions will be always false

Second, the set of conditions

```
V_BUSINESS_PROVIDER = valueGet
AND Upper(V_BUSINESS_PROVIDER) = Upper(valueGet);
```

is reduntant. If you need values to be exactly the same case (e.g. 'Word' <> 'wORD') you have to use only lines like this

```
V_BUSINESS_PROVIDER = valueGet
```

otherwise, if you don't need to compare cases (e.g. 'Word' = 'wORD') you need to use such conditions only

```
AND Upper(V_BUSINESS_PROVIDER) = Upper(valueGet)
```

Third. As I see the aim is to get column values into variables named after them. In this case you have to specify the column names in the select statement. E.g.

```
select business_provider
  into V_BUSINESS_PROVIDER
  FROM BUSINESS_PROVIDER_CONFIGURATION
....
```

Fourth thing is the using exception handlers for non-handling purpose is a bad idea. I'd recomment you to rewrite this part like the following

```
create or replace FUNCTION BUSINESS_PROVIDER_GET(valueGet IN VARCHAR2) 
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
v_value business_provider_configuration.billing_account_id%TYPE ;
V_BUSINESS_PROVIDER  business_provider_configuration.business_provider%TYPE; 
V_TRADING_NAME   business_provider_configuration.trading_name%TYPE; 
V_CUSTOMER_ID business_provider_configuration.customer_id%TYPE;
V_PROVIDER BUSINESS_PROVIDER_CONFIGURATION%TYPE;
BEGIN
  begin
    select ... into V_BUSINESS_PROVIDER ...;
  exception 
    when no_data_found then 
      V_BUSINESS_PROVIDER := null;
  end;

  if V_BUSINESS_PROVIDER is null then
    begin
      select ... into V_TRADING_NAME ...;
    exception 
      when no_data_found then 
        V_TRADING_NAME := null;
    end;
  end if;

  if V_TRADING_NAME is null then
    begin
      select ... into V_CUSTOMER_ID ...;
    exception 
      when no_data_found then 
        raise(...); -- though I'm not sure if you have to raise it, the no_data_found will get raised anyway you can handle the native exception
    end;
  end if;
end BUSINESS_PROVIDER_GET;
```

Comment: That is totally true. In my answer i was only trying to fix syntax errors with exceptions.
But yes,the point about variables is totally valid - I think the misconception OP has is that SQL is somehow executed from top to bottom

Comment: Thanks Please look also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59668860/pl-sql-how-to-return-whole-record