# PL/SQL how to return whole record

Tags: sql, plsql

I want to do a function that assumes a certain value. Then this value is searched in three columns, if it is found then it is returned, if not then the function will be terminated.

I am asking for tips on how I can solve it, I want to return the whole record.

```
create or replace FUNCTION BUS_PROV_GET_TEST(valueGet IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN 
         BUS_PROV_CONF%ROWTYPE 
         IS
         V_ROW BUS_PROV_CONF%ROWTYPE ;
    BEGIN
    DECLARE
        V_BUS_PROV  BUS_PRO_CONF.bus_provider%TYPE; 
        V_TRA_NAME   bus_prov_conf.tr_name%TYPE; 
        V_CU_ID bus_prov_conf.cu_id%TYPE;
    BEGIN
         SELECT *
          INTO V_ROW
          FROM BUS_PROV_CONF
         WHERE bus_prov = valueGet
           AND Upper(BUS_PROV) = Upper (valueGet)
          ;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN no_data_found THEN
            BEGIN 
                SELECT *
                  INTO V_ROW
                  FROM BUS_PROV_CONF
                 WHERE tra_na = valueGet
                   AND Upper(TRA_NA) = Upper (valueGet)
                   ;
            EXCEPTION
            WHEN no_data_found THEN
                BEGIN 
                    SELECT *
                      INTO V_ROW
                      FROM BUS_PROV_CONF
                     WHERE cu_id = valueGet
                       AND Upper(CU_ID) = Upper (valueGet)
                       ;
                EXCEPTION
                    WHEN no_data_found
                    then
                     raise_application_error(-20000, 'Not found');
                END; 
            END;
           END;
    END BUS_PROV_GET_TEST;
```

Table looks at follows :

```
create TABLE "BUS_PROV_CONF" 
(
BUS_PROV varchar2(256),
T_NAME varchar2(256),
C_ID varchar2(256),
NOT_TYPE varchar2(256),
PRO_TYPE varchar2(256),
BILL_AC_ID varchar2(256),
MAIL_ADD varchar2(256)
);
```

The star at the SELECT is underlined and I am getting PLS-00382 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best approach here is to use cursors. I tried to rewrite the code and here what I have. Try this out.

Not sure it'd work though, I did not have the possibility to run this.

```
create or replace FUNCTION BUS_PROV_GET_TEST(valueGet IN VARCHAR2) RETURN bus_prov_conf%ROWTYPE 
IS
  V_ROW bus_prov_conf%ROWTYPE;
  V_BUS_PROV  bus_provi_conf.bus_prov%TYPE; 
  V_TRAD_NAME   bus_prov_conf.trad_name%TYPE; 
  V_CUS_ID bus_prov_conf.cus_id%TYPE;

  cursor c1 is
    SELECT *
      INTO V_ROW
      FROM BUS_PROV_CONF
     WHERE bus_prov = valueGet
       AND Upper(BUS_PROV) = Upper(valueGet);

  cursor c2 is
    SELECT *
      INTO V_ROW
      FROM BUS_PROV_CONF
     WHERE trad_name = valueGet
       AND Upper(TRAD_NAME) = Upper(valueGet);

  cursor c3 is
    SELECT *
      INTO V_ROW
      FROM BUS_PROV_CONF
     WHERE cus_id = valueGet
       AND Upper(CUS_ID) = Upper(valueGet);

  c1_r c1%rowtype;
  c2_r c2%rowtype;
  c3_r c3%rowtype;

BEGIN  
  open c1;
  fetch c1 into c1_r;
  if c1%notfound then
    open c2;
    fetch c2 into c2_r;
    if c2%notfound then
      open c3;
      fetch c3 into c3_r;
      if c3%notfound then
        raise_application_error(-20000, 'Not found');
      else 
        V_ROW := c3_r;
      end if; 
      close c3%rowtype;        
    else
      V_ROW := c2_r;
    end if;
    close c2;
  else
    V_ROW := c1_r;
  end if;
  close c1

  return v_row;
EXCEPTION
  when others then
    if c1%isopen then
      close c1;
    end if;

    if c2%isopen then
      close c2;
    end if;

    if c3%isopen then
      close c3;
    end if;
    raise;
END BUS_PROV_GET_TEST;
```

Comment: When I am running I getting PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
 why it doesent return row ?

Comment: @GrafikKrystian
As I can get it you are trying to execute the plsql code from my answer only.

If I'm right, then the code I gave you is the just function declaration. You have to call it from another code routine.

This is how you'll get the row in to a variable

    declare
      qq business_provider_configuration%ROWTYPE;
    begin
      qq := BUSINESS_PROVIDER_GET_TEST(valueGet);
    end;

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra BEGIN and DECLARE in your code. The IS keyword is all you need before your declarations.

Additionally, maybe it would make more sense to use one query that either uses UNION or OR statements for the different columns instead of relying on exception catching? Just a thought.

```
create or replace FUNCTION BUSINESS_PROVIDER_GET_TEST(valueGet IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN  business_provider_configuration%ROWTYPE IS
    V_ROW business_provider_configuration%ROWTYPE ;
    V_BUSINESS_PROVIDER  business_provider_configuration.business_provider%TYPE; 
    V_TRADING_NAME   business_provider_configuration.trading_name%TYPE; 
    V_CUSTOMER_ID business_provider_configuration.customer_id%TYPE;
  BEGIN
    SELECT *
      INTO V_ROW
      FROM BUSINESS_PROVIDER_CONFIGURATION
     WHERE business_provider = valueGet
       AND Upper(BUSINESS_PROVIDER) = Upper (valueGet)
    union
    SELECT *
      FROM BUSINESS_PROVIDER_CONFIGURATION
     WHERE trading_name = valueGet
       AND Upper(TRADING_NAME) = Upper (valueGet)
    union
    SELECT *
      FROM BUSINESS_PROVIDER_CONFIGURATION
     WHERE customer_id = valueGet
       AND Upper(CUSTOMER_ID) = Upper (valueGet);
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'Not found');
 END BUSINESS_PROVIDER_GET_TEST;
```

Comment: If there is more than one row that comes back this will fail. You may need to turn this into a cursor and add some more processing around what you return, but this should get you on your way.

Comment: Now I am getting : SQL Error: ORA-06553: PLS-801: internal error [55018]
06553. 00000 -  "PLS-%s: %s"

Comment: When I am trying to test via SELECT BUSINESS_PROVIDER_GET_TEST('something') FROM DUAL

Comment: You declared it as a function, you can't use a simple select statement to test. You have to write a block and return the value into your rowtype

Comment: I have written :  BEGIN
 BUSINESS_PROVIDER_GET_TEST ('something')  ;
END;
 right now is not a function

Comment: You need a business_provider_configuration%ROWTYPE variable to return the values. The call will look like:   v_variable := business_provider_get_test('something');